# Fredo and Array Update in python

Tags: python, arrays

I will have an interview with a company which like the hackerearth.com. I don't know how to work and doing the code perfectly. Could you help me with the following example?
This is the example for the .hackerearth.com, however, I don't know that I should consider the constraint in the code? can I use a package like NumPy? or I should only use the basic calculation with my self? Could you check my response and let me know the problem with that? Thank you so much

Input Format:

First line of input consists of an integer N denoting the number of elements in the array A.
Second line consists of N space separated integers denoting the array elements.

Output Format:

The only line of output consists of the value of x.

Input Constraints:
1<N<100

1<A[i]<100

explanation:

An initial sum of array is 1+2+3+4+5=15
When we update all elements to 4, the sum of array which is greater than 15 .
Note that if we had updated the array elements to 3,  which is not greater than 15 . So, 4 is the minimum value to which array elements need to be updated.

```
# Write your code here
import numpy as np
A= [1, 2, 3,4,5]

for i in range(1, max(A)+1):
    old = sum(A)
    new = sum(i*np.ones(len(A)))
    
    diff = new-old
    if diff>0:
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: You have missed off the part of the specification that says how to calculate `x`. NumPy is NOT part of the standard library for Python, although it is an extremely commonly-used package. So unless Numpy can do the job significantly better or there is another need for it elsewhere in the software, I'd say that using it here is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't Code Review stack exchange, but:

- You don't say how to calculate `x`. It seems to be something to do with finding an average value, but no-one can judge your code without know what it's trying to do. A web search suggests it is this:

> Fredo is assigned a new task today. He is given an array A containing N integers. His task is to update all elements of array to some minimum value x , that is, ; such that sum of this new array is strictly greater than the sum of the initial array. Note that x should be as minimum as possible such that sum of the new array is greater than the sum of the initial array.

- Given that the task *starts* by accepting input, it's important that your program does this part.

```py
N = int(input()) # you can put a prompt string in here, but may conflict with limited output
A = list(map(int,input().split())) 
# might need input checks
# might need range checks
# might check that A has exactly N values
```

- you don't need to recalculate `old = sum(A)` every time around your search loop
- calculation of `new` doesn't need a `sum` at all - it's just `new = i * len(A)`
- there's no point in checking values of `i` at or below `min(A)`
- your search will fail if all values of `A` are the same (try it), because you never look above `max(A)`

These remarks apply to your approach; a more efficient *search* would be binary chop, and there is also a mathematical way to go straight to the answer from `sum(A)` without any searching:
`x = sum(A) // len(A) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `numpy` or looping for this. Get the average of the array elements, then get the next higher integer from this.

```
N = 5
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
total = sum(A)
avg = A/N # not checking for zero-divide because conditions say N > 1
x = floor(avg + 1)
print(x)
```

Adding 1 is necessary to make the new sum greater than the original sum when the average is an exact integer (e.g. 15/5 == 3).